# Vim remove whitespace for specific files

Tags: vim

I've been using the following technique in my .vimrc to remove extra whitespace at the end of a line...

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e
```

But I realised I didn't want that to happen with Markdown files (e.g. either `.md` or `.markdown`) so I have the following VimScript...

```
fun! StripTrailingWhiteSpace()
    " don't strip on these filetypes
    if &ft =~ 'md\|markdown'
        return
    endif
    %s/\s\+$//e
endfun
autocmd bufwritepre * :call StripTrailingWhiteSpace()
```

But that still removes the whitespace for all files.

So I then tried the following (which seemed better as it was shorter)...

```
let blacklist = ['md', 'markdown']
autocmd BufWritePre * if index(blacklist, &ft) < 0 | :%s/\s\+$//e
```

But, again, that still removes the whitespace for all files?

Neither of these techniques seem to work? They leave the whitespace still in the file?

Any ideas on how I can do this (at the moment I'm having to edit Markdown files in a separate writing app rather than Vim and that's quite annoying).

Comment: Remove the : before the call in the autocmd and put the substitution in a else block.

Comment: @romainl `:` is completely harmless. But he must add `endif` because without it all autocommands that will be executed later will be executed inside `:if`: see examples under `:h hex-editing`: they have `if` in one :au call and `endif` in the other and this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Kevin Sjoberg for the initial response, but it turns out I have a bigger issue.

Which is if I run `:set filetype?` from within my Markdown file then it reports back that Vim thinks the filetype is `modula2`

I'm not sure how I can fix this, so if any one knows then please do comment!

As a temp fix I've used the following work around...

```
fun! StripTrailingWhitespace()
    " don't strip on these filetypes
    if &ft =~ 'modula2\|markdown'
        return
    endif
    %s/\s\+$//e
endfun
autocmd BufWritePre * call StripTrailingWhitespace()
```

...so it checks for both `modula2` (whatever that is?) AND `markdown` files.

---

UPDATE: well it seems this is a known issue https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/issues/15 so I tried the suggested fix...

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.md set syntax=markdown
```

...but that didn't help, Vim still interpreted the file as `modular2`

Also tried adding the following into my vimrc file...

```
au! BufNewFile,BufRead *.md setf markdown
```

...but that didn't work to change the format.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Fixed it, the suggestion by both https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/issues/15 and Kevin Sjoberg were almost there.

I just added into my vimrc file a modified version of their suggestion `au Bufread,BufNewFile *.md set filetype=markdown`

Comment: That is easy to fix. Put a file with `au! BufNewFile,BufRead *.md setf markdown` in `~/.vim/ftdetect/markdown.vim`. Voilà! :)

Comment: Hey Kevin Sjöberg I don't have a ftdetect folder so I tried sticking it in my normal vimrc file but that didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: `cd` into `~/.vim`. Do `mkdir ftdetect` and then create the file and put the contents there.

Comment: @Integralist You must define this autocmd *after* the one defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`. Just putting it after `filetype plugin indent on` line may work (note: I mean *existing* line. Be sure there are no other lines with `:filetype` command after the autocommand; also note that some addon managers may call it as well). Files in `ftdetect` are also sourced after `filetype.vim` and they should be more stable then “putting after …” recipe.

Comment: ZyX thanks for the tip, it doesn't effect me so no need (but good to know). See my set-up here https://github.com/Integralist/Fresh-Install/tree/master/Shell

Comment: @Integralist the reason you would want to go with my solution is that it will wipe any existing autocmds for the given pattern. I would still suggest going with the ftdetect folder and using `au!`.

Comment: @KevinSjöberg is having a ftdetect folder a vim convention (it's not a plugin name or anything like that, but any time you want to detect a file type and run a specific command for that file type you would add a filetype.vim file into that folder)? Also, what's the difference between au! and au and autocmd ?

Comment: Yep, ftdetect is how Vim detects filetypes by default. It will read the contents of that folder. au is short for autocmd. au! is short for autocmd!. au! will wipe existing patterns for what you define, i.e., remove modula2 for .md extension and set markdown for .md instead. au would just append one.

Answer (score 3):

The first function should work except you should not be looking for `md`. `ft` is short for `filetype` which is `markdown` for [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) files.

By changing it as follows it works fine. (Tested on Vim 7.4)

```
fun! StripTrailingWhiteSpace()
  " don't strip on these filetypes
  if &ft =~ 'markdown'
    return
  endif
  %s/\s\+$//e
endfun
autocmd bufwritepre * :call StripTrailingWhiteSpace()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is simple, but has some shortcomings (e.g. it clobbers the last search pattern / search history). If you're not against installing a plugin, you can try my [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967). With it, you can exclude certain buffers by setting a flag, e.g.:

```
autocmd FileType markdown let b:DeleteTrailingWhitespace = 0
```

Comment: Hey Ingo Karkat would you be able to elaborate on what it means to clobber the last search pattern (example of what would happen) so I can better understand why that would be a concern?

Comment: Type `:history /` and you'll see your `\s\+$` pattern there. And your original version also puts it into `:echo @/` (the function avoids that).

Answer (score 0):

I realize you solved the problem which was more than just the function you were trying to setup.

However, I liked your initial "blacklist" approach with a filetypes list. So for anyone else landing here that likes that, this is what I have.

It also **saves your cursor position**, and puts it back after running the removal of whitespace.

```
function! StripTrailingWhitespace()
    " Preparation: save last search, and cursor position.
    let _s=@/
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    " do the business:
    %s/\s\+$//e
    " clean up: restore previous search history, and cursor position
    let @/=_s
    call cursor(l, c)
endfunction

let noStripWhiteSpaceTypes = ['markdown']
autocmd BufWritePre * if index(noStripWhiteSpaceTypes, &ft) < 0 | call StripTrailingWhitespace() | endif
```